# wc_update_order() Not Working as expected

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to update the customers' billing details in frontend. I have the following code:

```
if(isset($_POST['save_order'])){
    $update_billing_details = wc_update_order( array('order_id' => $update_order_id)); 
    $update_order_args = array(
        'first_name' => $_POST['billing_first_name']
    );
$update_billing_details->set_address( $update_order_args, 'billing' );
 if($update_billing_details){
    echo "success";
 }
}
```

What happens is, The first name is being updated after hitting the save button TWICE.

Example:

> The original name is 'John'. If I make it 'Johnny' and hit save, it still shows 'John'. And if I type the name 'Johndel' then hit save, it became 'Johnny', and so on.

But, if I make my code like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['save_order'])){
  $update_order_args = array(
                '_billing_first_name' => $_POST['billing_first_name'],
                'order_id' => $update_order_id
                );
  $update_billing_details = wc_update_order( $update_order_args ); 
}
```

Nothing's happening.

What am I doing wrong? I based my work through [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26677258/updating-woocommerce-order-in-checkout-page-instead-to-create-a-new-one).

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

-Eli

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use instead [**`update_post_meta()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) function, this way:

```
if(isset($_POST['save_order']) && isset($_POST['billing_first_name'])){
    update_post_meta( $update_order_id, '_billing_first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) );
}
```

You have to be sure that **`$update_order_id`** is the defined Order ID here.

As I can't test this I can't guaranty anything… I hope this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, [`wc_update_order()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_update_order.html#144) uses [`wc_create_order()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_create_order.html#81) function, so you can only update these parameters for now:

```
$args = array(
    'status'        => null,
    'customer_id'   => null,
    'customer_note' => null,
    'parent'        => null,
    'created_via'   => null,
    'cart_hash'     => null,
    'order_id'      => 0,
);
```